# Как сделать чтобы view адаптировалась под размер текста UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, view

Подскажите как сделать View чтоб адаптировалось под размер текста и если надо расширилось или уменьшилось.Это метод layotSubviews? может кто нибудь скинуть ссылку на урок или показать подробно?

Comment: View должен адаптироваться под какой текст? UILabel, UITextView или ещё что-то? И о каком View идёт речь?

Comment: У меня вью и в него помещен текст UILabel.Как сделать чтоб вью меня размера взависимости от размера текста.

Comment: Может Вы всё-таки кода немного покажете? Или у Вас всё через storyboard создаётся?

Comment: я все через сториборд создаю.Вам что на словах не понятно.Вы что не опытный разработчик что второй раз переспрашиваете

Comment: @ShurikTennisist вам пытаются помочь и все вопросы здесь по делу, от класса вью, содержащего текст и от способа, которым вы его создаете (в коде вручную, с применением автолейаута или в сториборд) зависит решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе имеющейся информации попытаюсь Вам подсказать решение. Итак, создайте в рассматриваемом `UIViewController` простой `UIView`, в который добавьте `UILabel`. Данный `UIView` отцентрируйте в `UIViewController`, и для примера сделайте его ширину равной 200 (всё это можно сделать с помощью NSLayoutConstraint). У `UILabel` количество строк должно быть равно 0 (это означает, что их отображаемое количество рассчитывается приложением), а края пусть будут совпадать с `UIView` (опять же с помощью NSLayoutConstraint). Для наглядности покрасьте `UIView` в какой-нибудь яркий цвет, а у `UILabel` установите прозрачный фон и ещё добавьте в него какой-нибудь длинный текст.

Всё вышесказанное в раскадровке будет выглядеть вот так:

[image: Настройка расположения элементов в раскадровке]

Как уже заметно на предпросмотре `UILabel` самостоятельно растягивается, меняя при этом размеры родительского `UIView`. При запуске приложения Вы увидите всё то же самое. И заметьте, код писать не пришлось.

Comment: Роман, Спасибо ! я понял уже сделал.Крепление не так шло.